# Highlight the value according to the specific position in x axis with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My aim to highlight the StockValue value above 0.5 with one colour and StockValue of the years  2002, 2003, 2012 and 2015 using another colour with ggplot. I am successful to highlight the value above 0.5 but not able to solve the second problem.

I have tried:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(Year = c(2001:2015), 
      StockValue = c(0.93, 0.32, 0.24, 0.53, 0.43, 0.53, 0.43, 0.58, 0.31, 0.52, 0.49, 0.27,0.34,0.48, 0.45))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=StockValue)) + geom_point(color = 'blue', shape = 18) + theme(legend.position="none") +  ggtitle("Stock Value")

highlight <- df %>% filter(StockValue>=0.5)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=StockValue)) + geom_point(color = 'blue', shape = 18, size = 2.3) + geom_point(data=highlight, aes(x=Year,y=StockValue), color='red', shape=18) + theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is perhaps to create the data you want to use first. Like so:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(above = StockValue>=.5) %>% 
  mutate(year = Year %in% c(2002,2003,2012,2015)) %>% 
  mutate(comb = paste(above,year)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Year,StockValue,color = comb)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue','violet','black')) + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]